# Optimization Graph

Tags: c++, optimization, graph

there is an undirected graph with some nodes V, and some edges E. Each edge has a limit of flow and a cost (price) of per unit flow. Some of the net nodes are consumer nodes which need some flow sent by server node which are also net nodes.

The supply of server node is limited by it's level with different price, for example:

level 0 can supply 1000 flow with a cost of 1000(total price not unit flow price), and level 1 can supply 1500 flow with a cost 2000.

Given a topology network which consumers location and demands both have been identified, we need to identify the number and location of the server to make the total cost minimal and the total demand is satisfied.

I am trying GA with minimum cost flow. but it is prematurely convergent.Is there a more appropriate algorithm or idea?
the picture is an example

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Why did you tag this c++? I don't see how it fits here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].